# Synchronization on methods

Tags: java

Here is a sample program.

The current behavior is, `waitandsweep` method is called by A waiting for sometime and then executes some work. While A is waiting, B is calling the same method which waits for sometime and executes the same work.

For Both A and B wait time will be 1000.

My expected behavior is B has to wait before calling the method, while A waits for wait-time and executes the work.

Meaning, the wait-time for A must be 1000 and for B it must be 1000+1.

```
public class Wait {
  long waitTime =1000;
  Object lock = new Object();
  boolean flag = true;
public static void main(String args[]){
  final Wait wait = new Wait();

//Create two threads:
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
     wait.A();
   }
};

Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
     wait.B();
   }
};

thread1.start();
thread2.start();

}
public synchronized void A(){
  waitAndSweep("A");
}

public synchronized void B(){
  waitAndSweep("B");
}
protected void waitAndSweep(String caller)  {


  try {

    long waitTime = getWaitTime();  

    if (waitTime > 0)
      wait(waitTime);
    SomeWork();
    System.out.println(caller + waitTime );

  } catch (Exception e) {

  }
}
private void SomeWork() {
  this.waitTime = this.waitTime + 1;

}
public long getWaitTime() {
  return waitTime;
}
public void setWaitTime(long waitTime) {
  this.waitTime = waitTime;
}


}
```

Current output :
A1000
B1000

Expected Output:
A1000
B1001

I think we need to do some lock notify logic.

As I am not aware of this, can someone help me in this?

Comment: You tagged this questions with [tag:java], but I cannot see any code here...

Comment: please clarify more. you want thread A to wait for 1000 ms execute and than B to wait for 1001 ms execute ?

Comment: Sorry missed to add the code.

Comment: Where is the wait(..) method? I guess it is the key to this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just mark waitAndSweep as synchronized: `public synchronized void waitAndSweep() { ... }`

See: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html

Comment: Create method that is synchronized. Your thread B will not lock(execute) on that method until thread A has release lock on method.

Comment: @MainshPrajapati synchronizing the waitandsweep method didnt work. Because First A comes into waitandsweep waits for 1000ms, meanwhile B comes into waitandsweep waits for same 1000 ms. because waitTime changes only after A executes SomeWork()

Answer (score 0):

Create method that is synchronized.

Your thread B will not lock(execute) on that method until thread A has release lock on method.